# How to assign multilpe GameObjects into one for Unity?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Basically I have a game where the player jumps from a truck to other trucks, and I want to reset my trucks position when the player dies so he can restart the level. Some of the irrelevant code such as the player movement I removed as it is not necessary for me to include. The code is like this so far:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector3 truckStart;
    Vector3 startPoint;

    //Assingables
    public GameObject Truck;
    public GameObject Player;
    public GameObject Spawn;
    public GameObject lava;


    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
        startPoint = Spawn.transform.position;
        truckStart = Truck.transform.position;
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collisionInfo)
    {
        if (collisionInfo.collider.gameObject == lava)
        {
            Player.transform.position = Spawn.transform.position;
            Truck.transform.position = truckStart;
        }
    }
```

How do I make my code so that instead of there being just 1 gameobject for my truck there is multiple? I've tried using tags to find gameobjects but when I do that it won't let me reset its positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you want, but It seems it's not that difficult. As you already know how to assign serializable values in Unity via inspector, just declare an array of `Truck`, like:

```cs
private Vector3[] truckStartPoints;

public GameObject[] Trucks;
```

And, as a general Unity coding tip, the following is better (unless you have to access it from other class):

```cs
[SerializeField]
private GameObject[] trucks;
```

This makes `trucks` not accesible from other code, but still can be serialized via inspector.

And initialize like this:

```cs
private void Start()
{
    truckStartPoints = new Vector3[trucks.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < trucks.Length; i++)
        truckStartPoints[i] = trucks[i].transform.position;
}
```

And reset like this:

```cs
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collisionInfo)
{
    if (collisionInfo.collider.gameObject == lava)
    {
        Player.transform.position = Spawn.transform.position;
        for (int i = 0; i < trucks.Length; i++)
            trucks[i].transform.position = truckStartPoints[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Dude holy crap thank you so much. I had literally spent hours trying to find out how to use arrays and stuff and you did it for me in a second like that. Thank you...the code seems to be working. (But how dare you downvote my question)